# Drop connection if upload speed exceed specific value

Tags: networking, server, bandwidth

I have a media server installed to my Ubuntu machine. I want to limit incoming data to my server per connection for uploads and if a specific bandwidth is exceeded, their connection will be dropped.

For example, when clients are streaming to my server, if they are exceeding the upload speed value (in kbp/s) specified by me, I want to drop their connections.

I looked at `tc`, `trickle`, `wondershaper` vs. but they are not dropping the connections.

Is there any program for this purpose or any advice or configure to those programs to achieve that?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/776/how-i-can-limit-download-upload-bandwidth