# limit internet bandwidth (17.04)

Tags: networking, software-recommendation, 17.04, resource-limiting

I want to limit the internet bandwidth to avoid causing a bad ping for other users in the same network.

I used to use `wondershaper` but it doesn't seem work on `Ubuntu 17.04` (kernel 4.10, 64bit):

```
sudo wondershaper enp2s0 2000 200

RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
We have an error talking to the kernel
```

I tried `trickle`, but it didn't work (unchanged bandwidth and only single application). I read that maybe `tc` could help me, but I failed at finding a way to get it to work.

Any ideas / solutions for my problem?

**Edit:**

[How I can limit Download/Upload bandwidth?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/776/how-i-can-limit-download-upload-bandwidth) and [How do I limit internet bandwidth?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20872/how-do-i-limit-internet-bandwidth) don't help, cause wondershaper sadly doesn't seem to work on 17.04, trickle didn't really work too and doesn't really fit my needs, and tc isn't explained in those answers.

Comment: didn't this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/20872/how-do-i-limit-internet-bandwidth

Answer (score 0):

Try this : https://github.com/chozabu/LinNetLim, it's an alternative to netlimiter in windows os.

Comment: installation failed (https://github.com/chozabu/LinNetLim/issues/3) and the program doesn't seem to be able to easily limit all ports at once.