# How to slow down internet for some apps?

Tags: internet

I want to slow down internet connection for some apps, so that other apps can have more MB/s. Is there any way to control the flow of internet between apps?

Thanks for response!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How I can limit Download/Upload bandwidth?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/776/how-i-can-limit-download-upload-bandwidth)

Comment: @Robby1212 Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think trickle is what you're looking for. https://askubuntu.com/a/181411/452485

`sudo apt install trickle`

Limit the upload and/or download speeds for a specific application using the following command.

`trickle -u (upload limit in KB/s) -d (download limit in KB/s) application-name`

Comment: Works just fine! Thanks!